# Best method or control to display text from a file in an asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, text

This may be a totally newbie question, but here it goes.  I have a asp.net web page that I need to display text from a .txt file.  I am trying to figure what would be the best control to do this with or the best method.  I looked at using an iframe, but this does a very poor job of displaying the text from the file (for instance no word wrap for an iframe).  I don't really expect anyone to solve this for me completely, but if you have any suggestions or know of any links to tutorials or explanations where someone has done this, I would be very greatful.

Thanks

Comment: What does your .TXT file contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example add a `Literal` control, assign `File.ReadAllLines("yourfile.txt")` to the `Text` property and replace `\r\n` with `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just read the text-file in code (using a streamreader for example). Once you have that text, just output it to your web page.

If you're using web forms you could place a label and then set the text of that label.
If you're using MVC you could put it in the ViewBag and then in your view output the value from the ViewBag (or use a custom viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. Make sure that the control that you use encodes the text in order to avoid XSS vulnerabilities (or encode the text manually if necessary). 
It might as well be necessary to substitute line endings with `<br/>` tags.